# Enable this command through button

Tags: if-statement, button, getusermedia

Right now, the following command operates automatically. I am wondering how I can create a button that will enable the getUserMedia command, and subsequently display the text below.

```
navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
navigator.msGetUserMedia);

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
navigator.getUserMedia({
video:true,  audio: true
},
function(stream) {
  // returns true if any tracks have active state of true
  var result = stream.getVideoTracks().some(function(track) {
    return track.enabled && track.readyState === 'live';
  });

  if (!result) {
    $('.abada').append('<h4>2000(works)</h4>');
  } else {
     $('.abada').append('<h4>2000(works)</h4>');
  }
  },
  function(e) {
  $('.abada').append('<h4>2001(does not work)</h4>');
 });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to use an `onclick` function. So we can use:

`onclick="function"` as an attribute for the HTML tag,

```
var element = document.querySelector("#button");
```

`element.addEventListener("click", function);`,

`element.onclick = function;` are both acceptable in JavaScript,

```
var element = $("#button");
```

`element.on("click", function);`,

`element.click(function);` in jQuery.
Shown below:

Using jQuery:

```
$('#button').on("click", function () {
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({
            video: true, audio: true
        }, function(stream) {
             // returns true if any tracks have active state of true
             var result = stream.getVideoTracks().some(function(track) {
                 return track.enabled && track.readyState === 'live'; 
         });
         if (!result) {
             $('.abada').append('<h4>2000(works)</h4>'); 
         } else {
             $('.abada').append('<h4>2000(works)</h4>');
         }
     }, function(e) { $('.abada').append('<h4>2001(does not work)</h4>'); 
    });
);
```

HTML:

```
<button id="button">Click Me For Streaming</button>
```